# show data in datalist from 2 table

Tags: sql

I Have two tables:

```
tbl_car_detail
--------------
CarID (primary key)
CarBrand
```

and

```
tbl_car_image
-------------
ImageID (primary key)
CarID (foreign key)
Image
```

I have inserted the following records into `tbl_car_detail`:

```
CarID                CarBrand
-----------------------------
1                    Audi
2                    bwm
```

I am inserting multiple images with the same `CarID` into `tbl_car_Image` like this:

```
ImageID                  CarID             Image
------------------------------------------------
1                        1                 Image1
2                        1                 Image2
3                        1                 Image3
4                        2                 Image4
5                        2                 Image5
```

I want show result in one result set from both tables. I am using this query:

```
SELECT     dbo.Tbl_Car_detail.CarID,dbo.tbl_mst_CarDetail.CarBrand , tbl_car_Image.Image
FROM         dbo.Tbl_Car_detail.CarID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      tbl_car_Image.Image ON dbo.Tbl_Car_detail.CarID = dbo.tbl_car_Image.CarID
```

Which results with this:

```
CarID               CarBrand                Image
--------------------------------------------------
1                   Audi                    Image1
1                   Audi                    Image2
1                   Audi                    Image3
2                   Bmw                     Image4
2                   Bmw                     Image5
```

However, I want only one image with per CarID result like this

```
CarID               CarBrand                Image
--------------------------------------------------
1                   Audi                    Image1
2                   Bmw                     Image4
```

Answer (score 0):

So you only want the first image for each CarID? This will do that...

```
SELECT dbo.Tbl_Car_detail.CarID,dbo.tbl_mst_CarDetail.CarBrand,(SELECT TOP 1 tbl_car_Image.Image FROM tbl_car_Image.Image WHERE dbo.Tbl_Car_detail.CarID=dbo.tbl_car_Image.CarID) AS Image FROM dbo.Tbl_Car_detail.CarID
```